# Referring to Corefs across multiple questions

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp

I am using the Stanford-NLP package in C#. I have been able to compile and execute such a package, but have had a difficult time with leveraging the coref package across multiple inputs, specifically, trying to "pre-populate" corefs on a second input from a previous input.

In my example program, I read in a set of text via stdin, and have the CoreNLP library parse through it using:

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, sentiment");
```

I made an instance of the coref with:

```
CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation coref = new CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation();
```

I am using this to parse my input:

```
var annotation = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
```

I am able to get corefs out of the code with:

```
Map graph = (Map)annotation.get(coref.getClass());
Console.WriteLine(graph);
```

What I am unable to get working is leveraging the results of a previous input as a coref of the next input.

For example:

```
Input 1: Jane went to the store. She was purchasing bread.
Coref Result: She -> Jane

Input 2: She also bought apples.
Coref Result: null
```

What I want to have is the input "recall" the previous corefs and "know" the "She" is Jane.

While I could concat the strings together, I am looking an interactive process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me concatenating strings is the only way. The way this tool(StanfordCoreNLP) works in general, is that you give text input to it and you receive a graph as an output. So, lets say text A produces graph A. What you want to do, is give text B and graph A, as an input to produce graph B, but only text input is possible. How is that any different from giving text A+B as input, to produce graph B though?

In specific, the only way I've found to get the pipeline to work is providing Annotation input, in the pipeline's annotate function(as you do). Here is the description of Annotation, in the tool's java documentation:

> An annotation representing a span of text in a document. Basically
>   just an implementation of CoreMap that knows about text. You're meant
>   to use the annotation keys in CoreAnnotations for common cases, but
>   can define bespoke ones for unusual annotations.

Using the variables in your example, if it were possible to do something like:

```
pipeline.annotate(annotation,graph);
```

Then you could take previous graphs into account. But why add that graph and not its respective text?

I may be missing something here. I know this isn't the answer you were looking for. To be frank, I would like to leave this as a comment(but can't, because of the bounty). Although I am currently using StanfordCoreNLP in java, for things other than co-reference, there may very well be a better(or actual for that matter) answer, as well as someone more qualified to give it.

Comment: The reason I am attempting to do this is to allow user input to be contextual based on previous inputs. If there are other tools to do this, then that would be fine. I am trying to use this tool as a "conversation", a software agent would respond to user input. To do so, it would need to recall references and corefs of the conversation, as well as gauge a general sentiment of the overall conversation.

So, as this is the only tool that I know of that can parse and infer sentiment including corefs, I am trying to get it to work with "previous graphs" and get my corefs.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use "previous text", instead of the "previous graph" representing it. I don't understand how that would reduce interactivity(performance is the only issue I can think of). Could you give an even more specific example, of the behavior you want your tool to have? Demonstrate such a conversation scenario, between the agent and a user. Show why concatenating text would reduce interactivity.